# Function converts image to bytes. I need to modify function to check if no image exists

Tags: vb.net, image

I wrote the follow function to convert an image to bytes:

```
    Public Function ConvertImage(ByVal myImage As Image) As Byte()

    'store image in memory before converting and
    'create memory stream, save image in proper format
    Dim mStream As New MemoryStream
    myImage.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

    'convert new stream into bytes and indicate size
    Dim myBytes(mStream.Length - 1) As Byte
    mStream.Position = 0

    mStream.Read(myBytes, 0, mStream.Length)

    Return myBytes

End Function
```

The function works great, however, I am struggling in trying to figure out how to best modify my function to also check if an image exist.  if an image exists, then convert, if no image exists, then return Nothing from a particular path and then convert.  Can I do it on this function, or do I have to write another function?

Comment: if myImage is Nothing then???

Comment: @Frank_Vr if image is nothing, then return blank.  this is an inventory database that sometimes contains images. Each product has up to 4 images.  So each image goes through the function to be converted. Right now I have to write 4 IF statements for each picBox, instead I want to re-write my function so if picBox is empty, then return Nothing.

Comment: why will this not work as the first line of code in your function: 'if myImage is nothing then return nothing'